# Websphere registry and repository (WSRR)

Tags: websphere, wsrr

I'm trying to install WSRR on Linux (Ubuntu 11.04), but without success. I think I'm lacking some important information about installation. I've read that it's a prerequisite to have WebSphere Application Server (WAS) and DB2 installed, but when I downloaded WSRR package it has its own version of WAS and during installation it offers me Derby DB. In order to install it I had to change bash for dash (or vice versa). In the end I tried create profile of standalone WSRR in Profile Management Tool but with no success. Did anybody success in installation of standalone WSRR? Please help me, I need it for my thesis.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I managed to install and run WSRR.

1. First of all you have to have OpenSuse installed.
2. Log in as root
3. Reinstall you web browser (I changed mozilla 4 to mozilla 6)
4. Launch installation ./launchpad.sh
5. Create profile with Profile Management Tool GUI
6. Run First steps console => change directory to profile_root/firststeps/wsrr, for example, opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/profiles/WSRRSrv01/firststeps/wsrr and ./launchpad.sh
7. Run server
8. Start the WSRR Web UI (if you have stand-alone server)

Comment: thx, but I've just found another error :D I can't change perspective in WSRR, so I see only configuration perspective. Nice thank you very much IBM and OpenSuse

Comment: I have latest WSRR, but it seems to me like javascript bug in linuxs mozilla

Comment: sorry, can't help with that. Contact your local IBM rep :-)

Comment: Don't worry I think no one can help me :D

Comment: Finally I've managed to add a WSDL document to WSRR and to use some perspective. All you have to do is to press Configuration --> Manage Configuration Profile --> Configuration Profiles --> Load Configuration Profile and select BasicProfile_v70.zip from directory ${Install_Root}\WSRR\config\

Answer (score 0):

Not a final answer... it seems you're installing on an [unsupported platform](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wsrr/sysreqs/). Never try this with commercial software, you will fail or will need hours and hours to get it up and running.

Comment: Hi, thnak you for your reply. I've downloaded and installed OpenSUSE 11.4 as it seems to be supported platform, but when I tried to start WSRR installation, it failed with message "Unable to find supported browser", which is weird because OpenSUSE has Firefox 4.0.

Comment: Did you follow the steps described in the [WSRR InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/sr/v7r5/index.jsp)? The link relates to version 7.5, not sure which one you use. You must exactly follow alll those steps. Those ... complex, comercial tools can be frustrating to install.